# Add Custom Javascript to Quick Launch? +Skype Button

Tags: javascript, quick-launch

I'm looking to add a [Skype Button](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/) which shows a Users Skype Status in the Quick Launch in Sharepoint 2010.

I can successfully add this Control to a Content Editor Web Part as I have easy access to the HTML Editor. I understand I can run basic Javascript functions like *alert* in the http:// area of the Quick Launch.

The code I am attempting to add to the Quick Launch is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/js/skypeCheck.js"></script><a href="skype:testskypeuser?call"><img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/bigclassic/tarponithelpdesk" style="border: none;" width="182" height="44" alt="My status" /></a>
```

Is it possible to add a control like this to the Quick Launch of Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the script is loaded (*skypeCheck.js*) you can probably just inject the `a` and `img`. For example using jQuery:

```
$('.s4-ql').prepend($('<a>').
  attr('href', 'skype:testskypeuser?call').
  append($('<img>').
           attr('src', 'http://mystatus.skype.com/bigclassic/tarponithelpdesk').
           css({border:'none',width:182,height:44})
  )
);
```

You can also just move it in the DOM, like this:

```
$('.s4-sql').prepend($('a[href^=skype]');
```

Comment: Using the jQuery above, would I need to add a Quick Launch item ahead of time, or will this directly inject the item?

Comment: For the first example you would not need the item ahead of time. For the latter you would. Choose which one to use :)